# best initial values for nls() function

Tags: r

Im trying to fit some data to a non linear function and I am using nls() function , however i can't find the optimum, can you suggest how to choose the best initial values??

```
a=0.003
b=5.001
c=37
d=0.42
B=-(b+1)/d
fit = nls(ydata ~ a+(c^(B)*d/xdata^(1+d*B))*exp(-c*xdata^(-d)), start=list(a=a,B=B,c=c,d=d),trace=TRUE, algorithm = "port")

I have been obtainig always this result:
Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts, upper) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
```

Comment: what are the ranges of your `xdata` and `ydata` vectors?

Comment: the data are given in this website http://www.clal.org.cn/personal/scgui/download/Recommended%20Articles/Additional%20Course%20Materials/DASL/Datafiles/Medflies.html xdata <-days and ydata is the mortality rate

Comment: As with **any** language or recursive fit estimator algorithm, if you initial guesses are not within the desired local minimum, you'll converge wrong.  However,  in this case it appears your `ydata` vs. `xdata` inputs are under or over-defined.  Perhaps duplicate values as would be found in a non-one-to-one relationship.

Comment: Well, I am trying to solve the next  problem, I have in this paper http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/08898480.2011.540173 on page 33, that these data about medflies is fitted to some models. As these models are non linear I am trying to use non linear least squares (nls function)... however I can´t obtain the same estimations.... Can you give me some ideas to solve my problem??